# How can I see all the incoming queries in real time to my MariaDB 10 server on windows?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I just want to see the queries coming in to MariaDB (very similar to mysql) in real time to help debug my application.

What windows frontends are there that do this sort of thing?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try `general_log`?

Comment: no but i'll investigate it